# do I need Windows 10 for Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-10, xamarin.forms

On the Xamarin website, it says:

> "The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. Xamarin.Forms Windows support requires Windows 8.1, and Xamarin.Forms UWP support requires Windows 10."

Does this mean if I want to use the UI controls and XAML in the Xamarin.Forms API for Android and iOS apps, I will need to have Windows 10? Or Windows 10 is needed only if I want to deploy my app on to Windows phone?

Update: Sorry I didn't make it clear on my question. So basically, I want to write an app that:

1. Can share the same source code for both Android and iOS.
2. Can debug on my Android phone, similar to the way I can do with Android on Eclipse (i.e. no need for Emulation, just load the app directly onto the phone and then debug through the Eclipse IDE).
3. Can take advantage of all the Xamarin.Forms control and XAML syntax.

Would I need Windows 10 for all 3 above? If not, which # does and which does not need Windows 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make cross-platform Android and iOS Apps with Xamarin, than No, you don't need to have Windows 10. Windows 10 is required in case that you are developing UWP App with Xamarin.Forms so that you can test it on your PC.

Comment: does that mean if I want to develop and debug apps with C# and XAML that will only run on Android and iOS, I won't need Windows 10?

Comment: As long as you are not developing and testing (for testing you need Win10) UWP App on your PC you are good to go with your current OS. If you want to make UWP App you can do it but you can not test ti because you don' have Win10.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 is needed only if you would like to create Universal Windows Platform (UWP) projects.

Comment: Incorrect. Windows 10 is only needed if you want to debug (and/or run) UWP projects. You can still develop UWP projects in other OS versions, so long as you have the UWP dev tools installed

Comment: For me developing without debugging and running is not developing to be honest, but I agree with you.

Comment: Is UWP only for Windows environments compatibility? What if I only need to develop app that run on Android and iOS? Also, can I debug in Windows 7 by loading the app to my phone and debug from there like I can do with Android on Eclipse?

Comment: Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is platform that runs on Windows 10 across multiple device platforms such as (Phone, Desktop, Surface, XBOX...). If you want to make UWP App to test it or debug it you need Windows 10. If you want to make Android and iOS Apps you can test app on real device or emulator.